# gnome-open window positioning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh, gnome-terminal

As some super users would know:

```
gnome-open /home/username/somefile.txt
```

will open a window in gnome.

Is it possible to open a window and place it a corner of the window from the command line?

```
gnome-open /home/username/somefile.txt -top -left
```

(I know the command is made up)
This would be the equivalent of opening the file and pressing ctrl + alt + num9.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, but it will not always work:

> gnome-open file.txt  &&  sleep 2 && wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -e
>   1,0,0,-1,-1

Comment: I used a combination of this and xdotool. Thanks mate